# How to merge list of dataframes all with same index and same column names?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, merge

I have a list of dataframe like this of 90 heat devices

```
data_list = [df0,df2, ... ,df89]
```

All of these dataframes in `data_list` have the same features (= column names):

```
("timestamp", "outside_temperature", "heating_generation", "power_consumption", "hot_water_storage", etc..)
```

All dataframes have the index : `timestamp` for the same period of time

I want to create now new dataframes which are having one feature but for all 90 heat devices

e.g for outside_temperature:

```
  timestamp        device_0, device_2, device_3 ,..., device_89
01.05.2022 00:10      15.03    14.39     15.69   ...   15.30
01.05.2022 00:15      14.94    14.20     15.30   ...   15.29
01.05.2022 00:20      14.94    14.05     15.29   ...   15.20
.
.
.
etc.
```

and that for all my features.

Any idea whats the best way to do so ? I was thinking about merging but couldn't find good advice, or do it by a for loops.

Comment: Do you just want to concat all your frames `pd.concat(data_list)`?

Comment: All you need to do here is concat on the common index

Comment: But I want to create then as much dataframes as features I have, so when merging on the common index I dont select my features - I guess there is still the problem that all features are having the same name for all devices or ? / How can I rename the column names then when just concat them ?

Comment: @It_is_Chris but I want to have for each single feature one dateframe ( this dataframe includes all 90 devices). If I do just concat I still have all features in one dataframe which is not what I want to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I followed your question correctly you could concat the selected columns by first using a comprehension then setting the columns names in two steps.  This does assume that the timestamps are the same in all data frames stored in data_list.

For example the following would concatenate all outside_temperature columns, leaving the columns name the same:

```
feature_df = pd.concat([x['outside_temperture'] for x in data_list], axis=1)
```

and then you could rename the columns with something like the following:

```
feature_df.columns = [f'device_{i}' for i in range(len(data_list))]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much this works for me - But one thing: my index (timestamp) is get removed after applying this - how can I kepp it ?

Comment: Is the timestamp an index or a column label?  The original question seemed to indicate both.  If it is a column label you can use df.set_index('timestamp') or you can explicitly set the index using df.index = df0['timestamp'] for each data frame prior to the concat.  OR you can set the index in feature_df.index = df0['timestamp'] after the concat.  Again, this does assume that all rows have the same timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

You can concat your dataframes and then transpose them using `pd.pivot`  function like in this small example

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'timestamp': [pd.Timestamp(2022, 1,1), pd.Timestamp(2022, 1,2)],
    'value':[1,2],

})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'timestamp': [pd.Timestamp(2022, 1,1), pd.Timestamp(2022, 1,4)],
    'value':[3,4]
})

dfs = [df1, df2]
# add df tag
for (idx, df) in enumerate(dfs):
    df['device'] = f'device_{idx}'

final_df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
pd.pivot(index = 'timestamp' , columns = 'device', values= 'value', data= final_df )
```